# Continued square roots sequence

Tags: radicals

Apologies if this has been asked before, I could not find it.

---

Define a sequence $a_n$ by $a_0 = 1$ and $a_n = 1+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}.$ Find the closed form, if it exists, of $a_n.$

---

So I can see this is just continued  square roots. I know how to evaluate
$$1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\cdots}}$$
to infinity, but i'm not sure how to evaluate for a finite amount of radicals. I have tried using the same method and considering the polynomial of which it is a root of, but none of these seemingly lead anywhere.

Also, if this could be generalized that would be helpful.

Comment: Writing the limit as $\varphi$, we have $\varphi=1+\sqrt\varphi$.

Comment: Yes, but how does that help in finding $a_n$ in general?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: $a_n$ is a root of $P_n(x)$ where $P_0(x)=x-a_0$ and $P_n(x)=P_{n-1}\left((x-1)^2\right)$ but I doubt there is a nice closed form for it.